# Efficient way to iterative Java Collection and doing some transformation on element

Tags: java, c++, collections, iterator

I am wondering whether there are some efficient ways to iterate a java collection of objects and doing some transformation. Here is an example i always see:

```
 public class MyObject {
    int data;

    public void run() {
        doTransform();
    }
    .....
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(){
        Set<MyObject> objs=..
        for(MyObject obj: objs){
            if(obj.getData() && other conditions ){
               obj.run();                
           }

       }
       //The iterator are also frequently used here ..
   }
}
```

Personally, i do not like this way shown in the main method as it requires more typing code and the code is not so clean... I prefer the way used in C++ (Only one line of code ). Example for above would be:

```
 for_each(obj.begin(), obj.end(), a fun object);
```

Comment: I'm curious what about this you consider "not so clean."  Just because the code is on one line doesn't make it "cleaner."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 8, you can do:

```
objs.stream()
    .filter(o -> o.hasData() && other conditions)
    .forEach(MyObject::run);
```

It's hard to imagine something that's much more concise than that (at least while still being readable!). Here's what it does in more depth:

- The first line creates a [`Stream<MyObject>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) for your `Set<MyObject>`
- The second line it turns that into a stream that allows only elements `o` such that `o.hasData() && other conditions`.

  - This corresponds to the `if` in your loop.
- Finally, the third line invokes the `run` method.

  - (`MyObject::run` is just shorthand for `o -> o.run()`, where `o` is of type `MyObject`.)

Comment: For Java 7 and below, what you have is about as good as it gets.